Failed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/apm"
I do get the following error while running my Github action
Error
Failed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/apm"
My config
commitlink.config.ts
module.exports = {
  extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional'],
}

package.json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^19.2.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^19.2.2",
    "@semantic-release/apm-config": "^9.0.1",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "semantic-release": "^23.0.8"
  },
  "release": {
    "extends": "@semantic-release/apm-config"
  },

ci.yml
      - name: release
        run: npx semantic-release --branches main
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}

Code reproduction

https://github.com/rbalet/scss-opinionated

Does anybody have an idea where the problem is?
